TV series with a smart female character whose brother or ex-boyfriend shows up who is smarter and is in some military/spy organization?
I am pretty sure this is a sci-fi series, but there's a chance it isn't. For some reason, I was thinking it was Stargate SG-1, but I can't confirm it. I don't remember a whole lot, but here are some points I think capture the essence:

The guy is well built - think Channing Tatum.

The lady is smart, maybe a bit OCD, a trait which he shares.

They're together for maybe two episodes, then she has him arrested, or maybe she just reports him to the higher-ups.

He portrays himself as some super-spy/special services guy when he shows up, but there's something off - he's not a super good guy - he lacks moral judgement, but he's definitely way skilled and part of an organization - either spy or paramilitary.

I seem to recall they are pairing up to do an investigation of a military organization where paperwork and a coverup, maybe murder, is involved, forgeries, etc.

The lady isn't the only main character of the show, but she's a regular and the guy totally shows her up to her peeps.


As I think of more points, or as y'all weigh in, I'll try to add more stuff. As for Sci-fi components, it's set on Earth, but that is probably just a one-off for these episodes. I don't remember anything particularly sci-fi-ish, but maybe alien technology (nothing I can specify) or alien's in disguise, but again I can't remember that being specific to these episodes. It's a little vague, hopefully, this is enough to kick things off.

@user108131 My first immediate thought also, but genders are reversed and as you said the other plot points don't match.

Maybe from "Eureka" (2006) TV show? Or Warehouse 13?

Are you remembering season 4, episode 10 of "Psych", with Juliet's brother Ewan?
Details which fit:

"the guy is well built - think Channing Tatum." - Ewan is portrayed by John Cena.

"The lady is smart, maybe a bit OCD, a trait which he shares." - Juliet is always portrayed as smart, capable, and somewhat Type A.

"They're together for maybe two episodes, then she has him arrested, or maybe she just reports him to the higher-ups." - The character appears in 2 episodes, and Juliet does arrest him.

"He portrays himself as some super-spy/special services guy when he shows up, but there's something off - he's not a super good guy - he lacks moral judgement, but he's definitely way skilled and part of an organization - either spy or paramilitary." - He's a former soldier turned mercenary/spy.

"I seem to recall they are pairing up to do an investigation of a military organization where paperwork and a coverup, maybe murder, is involved, forgeries, etc." - That's basically the plot of the episode.

"The lady isn't the only main character of the show, but she's a regular and the guy totally shows her up to her peeps." - Juliet is not the main character, but is in nearly every episode. And her brother is portrayed as being more bad-ass than her.


